# Merge cells conditionally from certain rows into one cell in Excel

Tags: excel, vba

In an Excel file I need to find all rows with duplicate email addresses and replace them with one single row where the SKU and the Title columns are merged into one SKU cell and one Title cell (using a separator like |). See below.

I need to turn these rows with four columns:

```
Email   Date    SKU Title

john.smith@company.com  2021-04-22  0520 9006   Calibration

john.smith@company.com  2021-04-22  0521 9101   Calibration

john.smith@company.com  2021-04-22  0554 8803   Sd card

john.smith@company.com  2021-04-22  0572 1754   Data logger
```

... Into one single row with the same 4 columns:

```
john.smith@company.com  2021-04-22  0520 9006|0521 9101|0554 8803|0572 1754 Calibration|Calibration|Sd card|Data logger
```

There are thousands and thousands of rows, so I really would be glad if I didnt have to do it manually.
Can this be done with a formula or a macro? Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

You can do it using `FILTER`/`TEXTJOIN`:

```
=TEXTJOIN("|",1,FILTER(C:C,A:A=G2))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I will try that formula.